# A manually created suffix for section titles compiled using tex4ht

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec, tex4ht

I am building a document that looks one way with `xelatex` and another *plain text file* appearance using `tex4ht`.  I produce an `html` document that then produces a great document that can be copied into notepad.

To this end, I am manually creating some formatting structures like a pseudo-underlined title:

```
TITLE HERE AND UNDERLINED WITH REPEATED SYMBOLS
-----------------------------------------------
Text of the document goes here
No bold formatting or anything is preserved from the html file
So I am not to concerned with customizing the formatting of the html output
```

As in the example below, I use the `HCode` detection block to toggle between versions.

I am pretty sure I should be close to the insertion of the symbols with the replication macro/newcommands, but I can't get `htlatex` to keep the suffix.  I don't have a great understanding of when the CSS file takes over or why this would be a problem, but I have tried a few different approaches, but in the MWE below, I have only kept (and commented out) those I felt were closest.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

    \ifdefined\HCode
        % appearance of sectioning commands should be taken care of in a custom cfg file for the tex4ht compile process
        %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147370/change-chapter-formatting-with-tex4ht-and-memoir
        \makeatletter
            \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalfont\scshape\raggedright}%
                %\newline\TextUnderline{section}%
                }
        \makeatother
        %\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries\raggedright}{Section \thesection, suffix }{0em}{}

    \else
        \titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]%
        \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}% 
    \fi


\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \EngBIRDreplication \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

    \NewDocumentCommand\TextUnderline{ O{1} }%
    {%
        %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276083/is-int-step-inlinennnn-inserting-something-after-it-finished
        \EngBIRDreplication{\stringlength{#1}}{-}%\hspace*{0.5em}}%
    }
    \NewDocumentCommand\spacers{ O{1} }%
    {%
        %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276083/is-int-step-inlinennnn-inserting-something-after-it-finished
        \EngBIRDreplication{#1}{~}%\hspace*{0.5em}}%
    }   

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\section{Hello World}


\clearpage      
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX commands are redefined after preamble, so if you redefine `\section` in the preamble, it will be overwritten. You should use `tex4ht` configurations for this stuff anyway. Look at [this older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263675/2891) of mine how it can be configured to produce wiki-like markup.

For your particular request, it is a little bit more complicated, as you must count characters in the section, including the numbering. I have no doubts that it can be handled from TeX with some effort, but much more efficient seems to me to use some higher level tool alter the HTML. Simple solution is to use JavaScript and HTML DOM.

Save this file as `underlinesec.js`:

```javascript
var undersecns = (function(){
  var getLength = function(el){
    // get text content of the element
    var text = el.textContent;
    // collapse spaces
    text = text.replace(/[ ]+/g," ");
    return text.length;
  };
  var repeat = function(str, count){
    var t = "";
    for(i=0;i<count;++i) t = t + str;
    return t
  };
  var makeEl = function(text){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","under");
    var t = document.createTextNode(text);
    div.appendChild(t);
    return div
  };
  var addUnder =  function(selector, ch){
    var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for(var i=0;i< el.length; ++i){
      var item = el[i];
      var length = getLength(item);
      // make string with repeated hyphen
      var newstr = repeat(ch, length);
      var div = makeEl(newstr);
      item.appendChild(div);
    }

  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // add commands for all section levels
    addUnder(".sectionHead", "-");
  });
})();
```

It will process all sections (they have `sectionHead" class), count characters of the section title and add string of`-` of the same length.

You have to insert it to your document, which you can do with this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{@HEAD}{%
\HCode{<script type="text/javascript" src="underlinesec.js"></script>\Hnewline}
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result in a browser:

[image]

It doesn't fit because proportional font is used, but the underline length is correct

Comment: Thanks, I assume the `js` file should be just in the same directory as the `cfg` file, but I can't seem to get  the instructions in this file to take effect.  I guess as well I should inquire whether you could tell me if there's a special developer version that includes the accessible version of the libraries of `js` or `HTML DOM` that I should perhaps be using on a windows - MikTeX machine instead.

Comment: @EngBIRD the js file should be in the same directory as your html document. javascript and dom are part of the web browser, you shouldn't need to install anything. but it is probably better to use Firefox or Chrome than Internet Explorer

Comment: Ah, it was my browser that couldn't process the additionally coded instructions. My apologies, and thanks for another truly exceptional solution.

Comment: you are welcome. I thought features I used were supported by all modern browsers, but they obviously aren't

Comment: One final comment:  I am observing that my string of hyphens is actually two character to long - probably because I don't have any numbers before the section titles.  I would have thought that the script would have detected that, but I am not sure.